# dgrid without store (using renderArray) : how to refresh a single row?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

My project use a dgrid with static values from an array. I need to refresh only one specific cell, but I don't know how to do it. The only way I found is to udate my reference table and call :

```
myGrid.refresh();
myGrid.renderArray(dataArray);
```

Without the `.refresh()` call, the new data is added to the grid. Without the `.renderArray(dataArray)`call, nothing happens. But when I do that, the grid is first emptied, then filled, so the display "jump". Is there a simple way to update a specific dgrid cell ?

Comment: there is grid.refreshCell  in the latest dgrid version 1.0.0

Comment: @xamiro : I don't use (and don't want to use) stores... I only use an array.

Comment: still the same, refreshCell is your friend

Comment: @xamiro. I'm sorry. As I only have a simple grid, no store or storeMixin heritage, grid.refreshCell is not available. `Uncaught TypeError: this._grid.refreshCell is not a function`

Comment: yeah, its in 1.0.x

Comment: ah, indeed, its in storeMixin. sorry. but you could still copy it over to your cusotm grid class, check the sources.